# Tag creation request (NFV)

Tags: support, tagging

Can someone with a high enough reputation score please create the `NFV` tag? We have an `SDN` tag but no `NFV` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are created by adding them to the taglist on a question. There's no option on the tag overview page to add a new tag without linking it to a question. As far as I'm aware you have more than enough reputation to do this. If not, you need to at least specify to which question this tag should be added.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realise I had enough reputation for that. I was referring to [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40534/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-sdn-nfv) questions, I have added the NFV tag now. Thanks!